# How to render a mail template with layout in ZF2?

Tags: php, email, templates, layout, zend-framework2

In the ZF1 I used the following code to render a mail body:

```
// View erstellen
$view = new Zend_View();
// Layout erstellen
$layout = new Zend_Layout();

// HelperPath muss hier nochmals übergeben werden da es ein neues View Objekt ist.
$view->addHelperPath('Own/View/Helper', "Own_View_Helper_");

// ViewScript
$view->setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/views/scripts/emails/');

// LayoutPath
$layout->setLayoutPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/layouts/scripts/');

$layout->setLayout('layoutMail');
$layout->setView($view);

foreach ($assigns as $key => $value) {
    $view->assign($key,$value);
}

$layout->content = $view->render($templateName);
return $layout->render();
```

I tried a lot but I cannot realise this function in ZF2. My actual code is this. But it uses the standard layout and I cannot get it in a string.

```
public function mailAction()
{
    $viewModel = new ViewModel();
    $viewModel->setTemplate("zhorty/test");
    $viewModel->setVariable('test', 'some value');
    return $viewModel;
}
```

Comment: For what reason do you need a **layout**? Usually the rendering of an email's body with a **view** is good enough. A layout (so a view encapsulating another view) is afaik overdone for emails.

Comment: @Jurian I think, that layout is a good place to store header and footer, such as logo and disclaimer, which are the same for each e-mail.

Answer (score 12):

Thank you! Your answer helped me!

I extended the code. So I can use a layout template as well.

```
$view = new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
$resolver = new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver();
$resolver->setMap(array(
            'mailLayout' => __DIR__ . '/../../../../Application/view/layout/layout-mail.phtml',
            'mailTemplate' => __DIR__ . '/../../../view/zhorty/test.phtml'
    ));
$view->setResolver($resolver);

$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTemplate('mailTemplate')
    ->setVariables(array(
    'test' => 'AlloVince'
));     

$content = $view->render($viewModel);

$viewLayout = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$viewLayout->setTemplate('mailLayout')
     ->setVariables(array(
            'content' => $content
));

echo $view->render($viewLayout);
```

Answer (score 10):

My answer is based on user1986560's answer and [How to Render a custom view with plugins in Zend Framework 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15073871/how-to-render-a-custom-view-with-plugins-in-zend-framework-2). I'm adding it as I think it makes things a little easier to implement.

I have an email layout and different content files. The layout can be reused and different content files added.

**view/email/layout.phtml**

```
<table>
    <tr><td><img src="header.png" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><?= $this->content; ?></td></tr>
    <tr><td><img src="footer.png" /></td></tr>
</table>
```

**view/email/contact.phtml**

```
<h1>Contact us email</h1>
</ br>
Name: <?= $this->name;?></ br>
Email: <?= $this->email;?></ br>
Message:<?= $this->message;?></ br>
```

In your modules conf, add the layout and different content files. By doing it this way, you can use view helpers.

**module.config.php**

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_map' => array(
        'email/layout'  => __DIR__ . '/../view/email/layout.phtml',
        'email/contact' => __DIR__ . '/../view/email/contact.phtml',
    ),
```

In your **controller/action**:

```php
// View renderer
$renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');

// Email content
$viewContent = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel(
    array(
        'name'    => $name,
        'email'   => $email,
        'message' => $message,
));
$viewContent->setTemplate('email/contact'); // set in module.config.php
$content = $renderer->render($viewContent);

// Email layout
$viewLayout = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel(array('content' => $content));
$viewLayout->setTemplate('email/layout'); // set in module.config.php

// Email
$html = new MimePart($renderer->render($viewLayout));
$html->type = 'text/html';
$body = new MimeMessage();
$body->setParts(array($html));
$message = new \Zend\Mail\Message();
$message->setBody($body);
```

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully one of my blog post will help you out, it is about [how to use Zend\View as template in Zend\Mail and add attachments in ZF2](http://avnpc.com/pages/zf2-mail-advanced-usage-for-template-multi-attachment)

It is written by Chinese, but I think just read the code is clear enough. Also you could [read it with help of Google translation](http://translate.google.com/translate?hl=zh-CN&ie=UTF8&prev=_t&sl=zh-CN&tl=en&twu=1&u=http://avnpc.com/pages/zf2-mail-advanced-usage-for-template-multi-attachment)

Comment: Plus 1 for a link in Chinese!

Answer (score 0):

For sendig Emails I recommend the following Module: https://github.com/WasabiLib/Mail

The Module is based on the ZF2 message and it is configured as a service. So you only need to call the servicemanager.

The body method is able to handle ZF2 viewModels. See the example below:

```
$mail = $this->getServiceLocator()->get("Mail");
$viewModel = new ViewModel(array('$yourVariable1' => 'yourContent1', $yourVariable2=>'yourContent2',...));
$viewModel->setTemplate("responsive");
$mail->setTo('recipient@domain.com');
$mail->setBody($viewModel);
$mail->send();
```

It is bundled with a responsive email template that you can customize. 
You only need to add the module to the application.config.php and you are ready to go.

Answer (score -1):

@user1986560 answer is not complete, cause you must need some basic helper like "url" with router and sometimes "basePath" also required.

Here is the complete code -

```
$myApp=Zend\Mvc\Application::init(require 'config/application.config.php');
$sm=$myApp->getServiceManager();

$view=new \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer();
$view->getHelperPluginManager()->setServiceLocator($sm);
$basePathX='/your-folder-from-where-you-want-to-run';
$request=$myApp->getRequest();
if($request instanceof \Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request){
    #die($request->getBasePath());
    $basePathX=$request->getBasePath();
}
$basePath1=explode('/', $basePathX);
/* please fix this path as your requirement */
array_pop($basePath1);
$bsPath=implode('/', $basePath1).'/';
/* following line will fix your router path, it is important */
$myApp->getMvcEvent()->getRouter()->setBaseUrl($bsPath);
$basePath=new \Zend\View\Helper\BasePath();
$basePath->setBasePath($bsPath);
$view->getHelperPluginManager()->setService('basePath', $basePath);
$urlHlpr=new \Zend\View\Helper\Url();
$urlHlpr->setRouter($myApp->getMvcEvent()->getRouter());
$view->getHelperPluginManager()->setService('url', $urlHlpr);

$resolver=new \Zend\View\Resolver\TemplateMapResolver();
$resolver->setMap(array(
        'wmsLayout' => APP_ROOT_PATH . 'module'.DS.'YourModule'.DS.'view'.DS.'layout'.DS.'layout1.phtml',
        'layout/left-menu' => APP_ROOT_PATH . 'module'.DS.'YourModule'.DS.'view'.DS.'layout'.DS.'left-menu.phtml',
));
$view->setResolver($resolver);

$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$tmpltFileToLoad=__DIR__ . DS.'your-file-to-render.phtml';
$tmpltIdx='_'.md5($tmpltFileToLoad);
$resolver->add($tmpltIdx, $tmpltFileToLoad);
$viewModel->setTemplate($tmpltIdx)->setVariables(array(
        'test' => 'shahadat hossain khan'
));
$content=$view->render($viewModel);

$viewLayout = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$viewLayout->setTemplate('wmsLayout')->setVariables(array(
        'content' => $content,
        'anyOtherVariableForLayout'=>'layout variable value',
    ));
echo $view->render($viewLayout);
```

Hope it my help someone.