# How to Render a custom view with plugins in Zend Framework 2

Tags: php, model-view-controller, zend-framework2

I'm working on an app that needs to send an email after a process is complete. Since the email needs to be HTML I had the bright idea of rendering a view as the email message body so that I can implement a "Click here to see this on your browser" functionality. This is all taking part inside a controller that implements AbstractRestfulController so the view itself resides in my front end module so that it can be accessed from a URL through a browser. However I am getting an

> No RouteStackInterface instance provided

error when I try to render the view.

This is my code:

```
use Zend\View\HelperPluginManager;
use Zend\View\Resolver;
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

//Instantiate the renderer
$renderer = new PhpRenderer();
$resolver = new Resolver\TemplateMapResolver(array(
            'layout' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../Application/view/layout/email.layout.phtml'),
            'email/view' => realpath(__DIR__ . '/../../../../Application/view/application/email/view.phtml')
        )
    );
$renderer->setResolver($resolver);
$renderer->url()->setRouter($this->getEvent()->getRouter());
```

I saw on the API documentation that you can set the router to the URL plugin by giving it a RouteStackInterface, hence the last line. However, that didn't seem to work either.

I would like to use the same view to send an HTML email message that has links in the message body & to display on the browser through a URL.

Any ideas/suggestions as to how to accomplish this?

**EDIT/SOLUTION:**

As per dotwired's answer below, getting the instance of the renderer from the service manager causes the plugins to be instantiated correctly. So this is the code that worked:

module.config.php:

```
array('view_manager' => array(
            'template_map' => array(
                    'layout/email'            => __DIR__ . '/../../Application/view/layout/email.layout.phtml',
                    'email/share'             => __DIR__ . '/../../Application/view/application/email/share.phtml',
                    'email/view'              => __DIR__ . '/../../Application/view/application/email/view.phtml',
            ),
    ),
);
```

REST controller:

```
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

//get the renderer
    $renderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');

    //Create the views
    $shareView = new ViewModel(array('data' => $data));
    $shareView->setTemplate('email/view');
    $emailLayout = new ViewModel(array('subject' => $this->_subject, 'content' => $renderer->render($shareView)));
    $emailLayout->setTemplate('layout/email');

    //Render the message
    $markup = $renderer->render($emailLayout);
```

Using the renderer from the service manager the $this->url() view helper work without issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just use the module.config.php of your module to specify your email template, like:

```
'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
        'user' => __DIR__ . '/../view'
    ),
    'template_map' => array(
        'email/view' => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/email/view.phtml'
    )
),
```

After which you can go on with [this part](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mail.message.html) of the documentation. You can then pass your view template from the renderer to the MimePart which will be used by the MimeMessage like

```
$viewModel = new \Zend\View\Model\ViewModel();
$viewModel->setTemplate('email/view');

$renderer = $this->serviceLocator->get('Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface');
$htmlPart = new \Zend\Mime\Part($renderer->render($viewModel));
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try it out in the next couple of days & let you know if it worked. Unfortunately the app is due tomorrow & we're going to have to ship version 1 with a work around.