# Using View Templates in Emails. How to more easily apply templates?

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I've been able to load a view template and use it to create the body of an email message. The code is similar to the answer here:
[How to render a mail template with layout in ZF2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14375869/how-to-render-a-mail-template-with-layout-in-zf2)

But now I'm looking to take this code and move it into a module that helps the rest of my application send emails.  I'm thinking I would like to make it as easy/transparent as possible to use views for all emails.

So the basic question is, **how can I setup the code to accept the information it needs to render a template and send the email?**

I already have my transport information held inside the service locator, and sending email works fine.  My primary concern is mostly the messy code needed for the template resolver:

```
$view = new PhpRenderer();
$resolver = new TemplateMapResolver();
$resolver->setMap(array(
                'mail' => __DIR__ . '/../../../view/communication/email/new-project.phtml'
        ));
$view->setResolver($resolver);
```

I am alright with having all the *.phtml for emails held inside the new module. There's no need to send adhoc emails out of the application (we use communications internal to the application).

**Is there a way to use the `module.config.php 'view_manager' => 'template_map'` and bypass the need to create a `new resolver()`?**  In that case I could setup the email code to accept the named template that should be in that map.

```
'view_manager' => array(
        'display_not_found_reason' => true,
        'display_exceptions'       => true,
        'doctype'                  => 'HTML5',
        'not_found_template'       => 'error/404',
        'exception_template'       => 'error/index',
        'template_map' => array(
            'layout/layout'             => __DIR__ . '/../view/layout/layout.phtml',
            'application/index/index'   => __DIR__ . '/../view/application/index/index.phtml',
            'error/404'                 => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/404.phtml',
            'error/index'               => __DIR__ . '/../view/error/index.phtml',
        ),
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply have to access the default `viewrenderer` via the `ServiceManager`.

```
 $viewRenderer = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('viewrenderer');

 $mailView = new ViewModel();
 $mailView->setTemplate('my-namespace/controller/mailtemplate.phtml');

 $mailView->setVariables(array(
    //k=>v paired data
 ));

 $renderedOutput = $viewRenderer->render($mailView);

 $mail->setBody($renderedOutput);
```

And that's pretty much it. Obviously though the concrete mail handling is stripped from this example, as you're mostly looking at another problem, given your description.

Comment: That definitely helps with the renderer. If this code is inside a Model and not a Controller, and is being called from another Module, what do I need to do to be able to reference the proper templates in `setTemplate()`?

Comment: Well, the templates usually are available on a per-module-basis anyways, so I'd argue as long as the Module is set up correctly, you wouldn't need to worry about adding view-paths from within your models. To access the view-renderer from your model, either inject the `ViewRenderer` into your model or inject the `ServiceManager`

Comment: The Model uses `ServiceLocatorAwareInterface` but the concern is that my **Communication** module should hold the templates for emails, but if I'm trying to use the model from the **Application** module, will I have access to the proper templates?  P.S. I'm testing and asking at the same time.

Comment: Looks like my last comment isn't a concern, running the model code from a different module still let me use the templates from the communication module. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, in ZF2, all configuration is stored in ONE big config. So every modules views are clumped together, too, basically ;) That's why it is so important of having unique module names :P

Comment: One last question, slightly off topic. Is there an easy place to see all the stuff that is autoloaded into the service locator.  How would I otherwise know that there is a 'viewrenderer' available in the locator?

Comment: Yip: https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ServiceManager/ServiceManager.php#L762